# How to get menus and submenus data from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a webpage using smart admin.I am getting left menu datas from an array.I need display menus and sub menus properly based on parent Id of each data using angular. But I don't know how to do it.Can anyone help me?please.

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.Menus = [];
            $http.get('/list/GetSiteMenu').then(function (data) {
                $scope.Menus = data.data.data.record;

            }, function (error) {
                alert('Error');
            });          

        }]);
```

Html:

```
<nav ng-repeat="menuData in Menus">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="menuData.url" title="menuData.name"></a>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a></a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

console.log($scope.Menus) will be in this format:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the array code with real data. What is the output ?

Comment: console.log($scope.Menus[0]['id'] would log 1.. $scope.Menus[1]['name'] would log "Our Culture" etc...

Comment: do u have submenus?

Comment: @SanjanaHE yes.if parent id is greater than 1 means that must be sub menu of one main menu.

Comment: @krish Please find my answer below ..which i had used in my code.. also post the complete json

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-bootstrap-submenu
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap-submenu

It's a module for add submenus items to parent menu items and it's easy to use

Answer (score 0):

Need to iterate over `menuData.menu_roles`

```
<nav ng-repeat="menuData in Menus">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="menuData.url" title="menuData.name"></a>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat ="subMenu in menuData.menu_roles">
          <a></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this according to your json
Use rootscope instead of scope to store Menus

```html
<section class="sidebar">
  <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
  <ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="{{menuItem.LiCssClass}}" ng-repeat="menuItem in $root.menuList" ng-class="{active:isActive('{{menuItem.NavigationURL}}')}">
      <a ng-href="{{menuItem.NavigationURL}}" ng-click="sidebar()">
        <i class="{{menuItem.ICssClass}}"></i>
        <span class="{{menuItem.SpanCssClass}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{menuItem.DisplayName}}</span>
        <i class="{{menuItem.TreeViewIcon}}"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="{{menuItem.UiCssClass}}">
        <li id="{{subMenuItem.TagName}}" ng-repeat="subMenuItem in menuItem.SubMenu" ng-class="{active:isActive('{{subMenuItem.NavigationURL}}')}">
          <a ng-href="{{subMenuItem.NavigationURL}}">
            <i class="{{subMenuItem.ICssClass}}"></i><span>{{subMenuItem.DisplayName}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried but i am not getting and your code is confusing :-(

Comment: I dint get you what You meant by smart admin.. What im doing in above code is get the menu details and store it in rootscope var.. and in view im accessing those using ng-repeat

Comment: If you need i can give you sample json i have used

Comment: please check this link.this is smart admin.They have already provide the design we just nee to integrate the code.

Comment: <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="menuData in SiteMenu">
                    <a>
                      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i>
                      <span class="menu-item-parent">{{menuData.name}}</span>
                      <b class="collapse-sign"><em class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></em></b>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

Comment: I have used this code.and I got all menus.but I need to split it as mainmenu and sub menu using paretId.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157345/discussion-between-sanjanahe-and-krish).